# Nested forEach and Asynchronity

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sequelize.js

I am currently working on an authorization functionality for a node.js website. I am working with Sequelize as an ORM and Passport as a login manager. To enable authorization functionality I want to add an authorization-name array (just strings) to the request Object (i.e. `["manageDelete", "manageAdd", "userManage"]`). I want to do that in the `passport.deserializeUser()` method.

Here is some additional information:

The authorizations are stored in a MySQL database table called `authorizations`. This table is associated to another table called `roles` in a `n to m` relation (what I ultimately want to achieve is to bundle the authorizations together to make managing the authorizations more easy).

I have huge problems with async code because this topic is very new to me. My code to accumulate all the authorizations of the roles of a user is this:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  var currUser;
  models.User.findById(id)
  .then((user) => {
    currUser = user;
    //gets array of associated roles for this user
    return user.getRoles(); 
  })
  .then((roles) => {
    var authArr = [];
    roles.forEach((role) => {
      //gets array of associated authorizations for this role
      role.getAuthorizations().then((auths) => {
        auths.forEach((auth) => {
          authArr.push(auth.name);
        });
      });
    });
    return authArr;        
  })
  .done((authArr) => {
    done(null, {user: currUser, authArr: authArr});
  });
});
```

I know that because of the asychronosity the `done()` method is called before any of the promises are resolved, but I can not find any way to prevent that from happening. I have tried countless different patterns (e.g this: https://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/patterns-asynchronous-programming-promises/, or async.js') but I can not get it to work.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any solution without using any additional modules? Help would be appreciated a lot. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialize uses bluebird promises, and bluebird has an `.each` method that gets you what you need. I think this is much more concise than the previous solution. As a side note, the fact that you are using arrow functions indicates you are using es6, in which case I prefer const/let over var. The following should work, but you might be able to come up with an even more elegant solution usings bluebird's map/reduce methods:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  let currUser;
  const authArr = [];
  return models.User.findById(id)
    .then((user) => {
      currUser = user;
      //gets array of associated roles for this user
      return User.getRoles();
    })
    .each((role) => {
    //gets array of associated authorizations for this role
      return role.getAuthorizations().each((auth) => {
         authArr.push(auth.name);
      });
    })
    .then(() => {
      done(null, {user: currUser, authArr: authArr});
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you don't return a promise in your second `then()`, so the empty `authArr` gets returned immediately.

What you should do is :

1. Return a promise in your second `then()`;
2. Use something like [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) to make sure all your `role.getAuthorization()` calls are finished before resolving the promise.

Here is how I would do it.

```
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  var currUser;
  models.User.findById(id)
  .then((user) => {
    currUser = user;
    //gets array of associated roles for this user
    return user.getRoles(); 
  })
  .then((roles) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // Return a promise here. The next then() will wait for it to resolve before executing.
      var authArr = [];
      async.each(roles, (role, callback) => { // Use async.each to have the ability to call a callback when all iterations have been executed
        //gets array of associated authorizations for this role
        role.getAuthorizations().then((auths) => {
          auths.forEach((auth) => {
            authArr.push(auth.name);
          });
          callback(); // Tell async this iteration is complete.
        });
      }, (err) => { // Only called when all iterations have called callback()
        if(err) reject(err);
        resolve(authArr); // Resolve the promise so the next .then() is executed
      });
    });
  })
  .then((authArr) => {
    done(null, {user: currUser, authArr: authArr});
  });
});
```